# Azure Policy to restrict role based access control(IAM) to users at Resource group level in Azure

Tags: json, azure, azure-policy

We were trying to implement a policy in azure to restrict role based assignment. We referenced below github policy, but during testing we observed it's not evaluating the roledefinitionIds defined in the parameter.

**https://github.com/Azure/azure-policy/blob/master/samples/Authorization/allowed-role-definitions/azurepolicy.json**

Tested with below roleIDs parameter -

b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c (Contributor Role)

acdd72a7-3385-48ef-bd42-f606fba81ae7 (Reader Role)

Ideally, it should whitelist the role IDs defined in the parameter, and deny the role assignment for other role IDs. But for some reason, during evaluation Azure policy service is not taking into account those role IDs defined in the parameter and instead restricting role based assignment for all the roles.
Need help in troubleshooting this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with this Role Definition ID and worked for me:

```
/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c
```

And if you are assigning the policy from Azure Portal and you want to provide multiple values, you need to put (;) semi-colon between the values.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. We were scoping the policy to a specific Resource group & giving the full roledefinition ID with subscription details -
/subscriptions/%YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_ID%/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c
 It wasn't working, it worked when updated parameter value without subscription detail -
/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c

Answer (score 0):

You may input an invalid id. A valid Role definition id look like:

```
/subscriptions/%YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_ID%/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the reply. We have tested giving roleDefinitionIds like this as well. Still it restricts role assignment for all the roles. Ideally, it should have allowed role assignment to user's for "Contributor" role & should restrict role assignment for other roles. Can you please help with this issue.